# Convert Multi-Columns to Rows

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, rows

I have a legacy table with the following columns.

```
Create Table test
( id varchar(50)
, code1 varchar(50)
, codeDesc1 varchar(50)
, code2 varchar(50)
, codeDesc2 varchar(50)
, code3 varchar(50)
, codeDesc3 varchar(50)
, code4 varchar(50)
, codeDesc4 varchar(50)
, code5 varchar(50)
, codeDesc5 varchar(50)
, code6 varchar(50)
, codeDesc6 varchar(50)
)

insert into test (id, code1, codeDesc1, code2, codeDesc2, code3, codeDesc3, code4, codeDesc4, code5, codeDesc5, code6, codeDesc6)
values ('1','100.1', 'first code','100.2', 'Second code','100.3', 'Third code','100.4', 'Fourth code','100.5', 'Fifth code','100.6', 'Sixth code')

insert into test (id, code1, codeDesc1, code2, codeDesc2, code3, codeDesc3, code4, codeDesc4, code5, codeDesc5, code6, codeDesc6)
values ('2','100.1', 'first code','100.2', 'Second code','100.3', 'Third code','100.4', 'Fourth code','100.5', 'Fifth code','100.6', 'Sixth code')

select * from test
```

returns as following:

```
id, code1, codeDesc1, code2, codeDesc2, code3, codeDesc3, code4, codeDesc4, code5, codeDesc5, code6, codeDesc6

1,100.1, first code,100.2, Second code,100.3, Third code,100.4, Fourth code,100.5, Fifth code,100.6, Sixth code

2,100.1, first code,100.2, Second code,100.3, Third code,100.4, Fourth code,100.5, Fifth code,100.6, Sixth code
```

But i want to get the data back as shown below:

```
ID, Code, Description

1, 100.1, First Code
1, 100.2, Second Code
1, 100.3, Third Code
1, 100.4, Fourth Code
1, 100.5, Fifth Code
1, 100.6, Sixth Code
2, 100.1, First Code
2, 100.2, Second Code
2, 100.3, Third Code
2, 100.4, Fourth Code
2, 100.5, Fifth Code
2, 100.6, Sixth Code
```

Can anyone help me how to do that, please?

I have tried the UNPIVOT but did not give me the exact result that i was looking for.  Here is the query i used but needs to be tweaked to get the exact result where I am finding the difficult time.

```
SELECT Id, FieldCode , FieldValue
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  id, code1, codeDesc1, code2, codeDesc2, code3, codeDesc3, code4, codeDesc4, code5, codeDesc5, code6, codeDesc6
        FROM test
    ) MyTable
    UNPIVOT
    (FieldValue FOR FieldCode IN (code1, codeDesc1, code2, codeDesc2, code3, codeDesc3, code4, codeDesc4, code5, codeDesc5, code6, codeDesc6))AS MyUnPivot
```

Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: What is this ? SQL or something like that ? Please tag appropriately

Comment: Do you want DB to output like that or do you want some programming language to print out like that?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, I need the query to do the transformation because I have to take this informaiton and update another table. I know i could use cursors but i don't like cursors and i know there is a way to do it with PIVOT/UNPIVOT commands but something is missing and i don't see it.

Comment: Since i cannot answer my own question right now, here is the resolution:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind, found the answer.  Thanks to this wonderful Mangal's website http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2009/04/unpivot-multiple-columns.html

And here is my query that resolved my problem:  I posting here so that if anyone who looks

```
SELECT Id, FieldCode, FieldValue
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  id, code1, codeDesc1, code2, codeDesc2, code3, codeDesc3, code4, codeDesc4, code5, codeDesc5, code6, codeDesc6
        FROM test
    ) MyTable

    UNPIVOT
    (FieldCode FOR FieldCodes IN (code1, code2, code3, code4, code5, code6))AS CODE

    UNPIVOT
    (FieldValue FOR FieldValues IN (codeDesc1, codeDesc2, codeDesc3, codeDesc4, codeDesc5, codeDesc6))AS FieldValues

WHERE RIGHT(FieldCodes,1) =  RIGHT(FieldValues,1)
```

Now the trick part to get the right result back is in the WHERE clause at the end which is depend on the column names you used.  So, try to understand the code before you try to play with it.

Also, its a good idea to check for ISNULL in the intial query where you're returning the orginal columns.  Because once it is in UNPIVOT mode you don't have a change to check for it and might casue an error.

Good Luck!